# contao CMS - i dont understand link system

Tags: php, url, content-management-system, friendly-url, contao

I have a problem because I dont't understand system of links in contao (http://demo.contao.org/) but not only in this CMS, Can you help me?
So:
We ALWAYS have link as:
`www.something.xx/title-for-example-news.htm`,

And the extension is always `htm` (never `php`!), no have id of e.g news, is it a good solution? How does it work?

I know way that we have a link for example www.sometking.xx/321-title-for-example-news.htm,
where 321 is id news so we can get easy and fast date from e.g. database, and no colision.

How does it work in contao case? it is fast? Maybe static array of routing? What do you think about it? It looks very pretty but is it fast?

Answer (score 1):

Just came across your question by chance. If you're still interested, here you go.

It's just as fast as the link with the id included. Both systems work by looking up the page name or id in the database; contao stores the permalink in the alias column of tl_page.

There is an issue if you alter the page name / alias though: contao does not have a fallback to the id if the alias is not found, so browsing the old page name returns a 404. This differs from Wordpress, for example. Wordpress will never changes the permalink even if you change the name of the page or post. After all, a PERMAlink should never change!